# How to disable babel-loader caching in create-create-app project?

Tags: node.js, create-react-app

I am developing a [create-create-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) project and noticed that when dependencies in `node_modules` are updated manually, changes does not make their way to browser.

After digging a little, I discovered that dependencies are now cached in `node_modules/.cache/babel-loader`.

Is there a way to disable cache for single or all dependencies?

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: I am having a similar issue. Any solution?